# Caching in VBA (Excel 2010) to connect to SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, caching, sql-server-express

I have an excel 2010. In the VBA code, one procedure fetches data from SQPEXPR 2008.
There are repeated calls, and many times same/filter data is fetched (which is already present in the excel document).

It makes a good use case to apply caching (for performance improvement).

Is it possible? Is yes how?

SQL Native Client is used to connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

When you update the underlying data that you wish to cache, also store the date updated. This could be done manually or via a trigger.

When you perform your query for the main data in Excel, also query for and store in the Excel spreadsheet the date last updated.

Finally, when you perform your data-refresh operation from Excel, first query to see if the current last-updated date is the same as the stored last-updated date. If so, there is no need to refresh the data.

If your data has an inherent "last updated" date and there is an index of any kind with this value as the first column within it, then you already have your "last updated date" stored just fine--it will take only one seek to read the most recent updated date, from which you can derive the same optimization.

```
SELECT TOP 1 DateChanged FROM dbo.YourTable ORDER BY DateChanged DESC;
```

Assuming that index I was talking about on `DateChanged`, you've got your "table last updated" date. Also assuming, of course, that every operation on the table will faithfully update this date when inserting or updating, and that rows are never deleted, just marked inactive (otherwise you would not know to remove a row).

Either way--explicitly saving a separate last-updated date or using a column implicitly, you now have a way to cache your data.

It may help you to think about how browsers and web servers perform this task, which is pretty much exactly how I outlined it: the file being requested has a modified date, and this data is exchanged with the client browser first. Only if the file has a newer date than the cached copy the browser has does the browser request the actual file contents.